# LINQ help for a beginner selecting multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, repository, viewmodel

I have the following repository that includes three methods for returning my db objects, the first two queries work fine as they simly return one list of data, however as the thrird method requires a selection from both tables im a bit confused with how to do this.

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction as how to write a LINQ query to select from two related tables to pass into the last method (CustomerAndSites) in the repository shown below - the tables are related on a customer ID field,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CustomerDatabase.Domain.Abstract;
using CustomerDatabase.Domain.Concrete;
using CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CustomerDatabase.Domain.Concrete
{
 class SqlCustomersAndSitesRepository : ICustomersAndSitesRepository
{
    public Table<CustomerSite> customerSitesTable;
    public Table<Customer> customerTable;                              


    public SqlCustomersAndSitesRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        customerSitesTable = (new  DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<CustomerSite>();
        customerTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Customer>();
    }

    public IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites
    {
        get { return customerSitesTable; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return customerTable; }
    }

    public IQueryable <ICustomersAndSitesRepository> CustomerAndSites
    {
        get { return CustomerAndSites; }
    }

}
```

}

====Update

This is my ICustomersAndSitesM interface, where do i define the CustomersAndSitesMix, do i need to create that as a seperate entity? i have a view model in my UI project that contains the properties for both objects.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities;

namespace CustomerDatabase.Domain.Abstract
{
    interface ICustomersAndSitesM
    {
        IQueryable Customers { get; }
        IQueryable CustomerSites { get; }
    }

}

Comment: Why would you want to return an IQueryable of ICustomersAndSitesRepository? It doesn;t make any sense to me

Comment: What are you doing in your constructor? !  Have you run/tested any of this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two tables are actually properly linked with a foreign key, LINQ will pull in the child records as well when you pull in the parent records. You need to examine the model that your DataContext returns when you are debugging and you should be able to see any linked records with enough digging. For example, if you have Sites linked to Customers, in your Customer domain model result, you should see a field called "Sites" that is a list of site domain models linked to the customer.

Comment: thanks for your advice, my tables are linked by a foreign key, but the only way i can get access to both objects from the model is to use a viewmodel that contains properties for both objects, do i need to decorate the entities with anything to define the foreign key relationship?

Comment: You shouldn't need to if it's already represented in your database. When you drag your tables in the model designer window thingy, if you see the relationship lines between the two tables, you should be good... Wait... are you using Entitity Framework? I'm describing how it works with LINQ to SQL. I don't have experience with EF. My advice may be moonman language for you if you're rocking EF.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an 'ICustomersAndSitesRepository', I guess you actually want to get an 'CustomersAndSitesMix'. If so, you could do this :

```
public IQueryable<ICustomersAndSitesM> CustomerAndSites
{
    get
    {
        return from customer in customerTable
               join site in customerSitesTable
                    on customer.PLACEKEYHERE equals site.PLACEKEYHERE
               select new CustomersAndSitesMix(customer, site);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll understand that "CustomersAndSitesMix" is just any object that contains a mix of informations from both classes and has a constructor that takes the two class as a parameter.

Comment: thanks for your help, im guessing that ICustomerAndSitesM is similar to what i had called ICustomersAndSitesRepository, this just had information for both entities (ive updated the question  to show the ICustomerAndSitesM. Not sure where to setup the CustomersAndSitesMix, does this need to be defined in the interface, ICustomerAndSitesM?